# Failed to open database with message 'database is locked in ios using sqlite3

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

I am facing below issues related to sqlite database in iOs even I have explicitly close the database before open the database but still I am facing same issues again and again.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to open database with message 'database is locked'.'

Here is my code

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO myusertbl (username,password) VALUES (?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text( statement,1, [self.username UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text( statement,2, [self.userpass   UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"You have Sucessfully saved!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to Save!");
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.",           sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    statement = nil;
}
```

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're closing the database using sqlite3_close API;

```
sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply................................................... yes I have added close statement. have you faced SQLITE_MISUSE error ?